# WPF XAML data binding with dynamically resizing UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a UserControl with a grid containing text boxes. This object dynamically resizes itself with the text in the boxes. I need to bind the dimensions of this object to my model. Binding the 'Width' and 'Height' of the UserControl or Grid will break the dynamic resize, as the I am now stuck with whatever is the initial size declared in the model. I tried using 'minHeight' and 'minWidth' but these will not send data back to the model, as the minimum dimension never change. I have tried to fiddle with different modes(Oneway, ToWay etc..) but without luck.

So to sum up: I need a way to bind the dimensions while maintaining the dynamic resize with the text in the text boxes.

```
<UserControl x:Class="_02350Demo.View.ClassBoxUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
         xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}"
         Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}">
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="Z" Command="{Binding UndoCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="Y" Command="{Binding RedoCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>


<Grid>
    <Rectangle Opacity="{Binding DataContext.ModeOpacity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" StrokeThickness="6" StrokeDashArray="3.1">
        <!-- The fill (background) color of the ellipse is a radial (center to edge) gradient (more than one color) brush. -->
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.0" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>


        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseDownShapeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseMoveShapeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseUpShapeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Rectangle>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ContentClass}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Gray" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ContentFields}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Gray"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ContentMethods}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Gray"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: While width and height are used for fixed, user set sizes you may be looking for ActualWidth and ActualHeight instead. Those contain the actual size of the component as calculated and displayed by WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want your view model to know about the dynamic size of the `UserControl`, you could handle the `SizeChanged` event of the `UserControl` and set the `Width` and `Height` source properties of your view model to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties of the `UserControl` respectively:

```
private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = DataContext as YourViewModel;
    vm.Height = ActualHeight;
    vm.Width = ActualWidth;
}
```

You may wrap this in a behaviour if you want to: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF